# <TableLayout><TableRow><LinearLayout> hates me. Force close on run. Android

Tags: android, xml, tablelayout, android-linearlayout

all.  I'm working on setting up a home screen layout for an Android app in which there is a 4x4 grid of launch icons.  My current structure for this is like this:

```
<TableLayout>
  <TableRow>
    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical">
      <ImageButton>
      <TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
  </TableRow>
  ...
  ...
  ...
</TableView>
```

When I run this, I get a force-close immediately.  If I remove the LinearLayout from the equation, it works, but I don't get the alignment I want.  Is there something inherently wrong with putting a linearlayout inside of a tablerow?  Or is there probably something else going on here?  As far as I can tell, my xml is all valid and I think I have all the required attributes I need. This is kind of driving me nuts, as there does not appear to be any documentation about this setup.

Comment: What is the stack trace of the force close?  Run adb logcat, or view the Logcat tab in eclipse.

Comment: Shouldn't </TableView> be </TableLayout>

Comment: I don't remember what exactly solved this, but I was unfamiliar with logcat at the time.  After finding it the problem was almost instantly solved.  I was new to stack overflow at the time and didn't understand the follow-up etiquette. Upvoted both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem a few times myself and usually it is a missing layout property such as `android:layout_height` or something. As it has already been mentioned it is advisable to just go ahead and check your logcat to see what exactly is causing the problem. A structure of a `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout` within a `TableLayout` (i.e. `TableRow`) however generally works out fine - even though I do not have the experience to say if it is best practice to do so.

Answer (score 0):

I get the same thing.

```
D/AndroidRuntime( 1378): Shutting down VM
W/dalvikvm( 1378): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1378): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime( 1378): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{...}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #19: Error inflating class LinearyLayout
```

Not a very descriptive trace, but I guess we simply are not allowed to make our layouts like this.

Comment: #19: Error inflating class **LinearyLayout**